# How to change Firestore query depending on user selection?

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have an app that contains categories list in recyclerview. I also have recyclerview that shows posts based on selected categories. These 2 recyclerviews are in one fragment. What I want to achieve is that when choosing particular category lets suppose "Business" I want to show posts from that specific category. So far, I tried something like this but to no avail:

```
Query query = postRef.whereEqualTo("postCategory", selectedCategory).orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

[image]

Comment: To solve this, you should create an index. Please check the duplicate answer.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added index already before stumbling upon this issue